# Recursively defines function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Find $f(2),f(3),f(4)$, and $f(5)$ if $f$ is defined recursively by $f(0)=-1$, $f(1)=2$, and for $n=1,2,\ldots$

$$f(n+1)= 3f(n)^2 - 4f(n-1)^2$$

Comment: Hint : $f(2)=f(1+1)=3f(1)^2-4f(1-1)^2=3f(1)^2-4f(0)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a matter of substituting values into the recurrence. For example, when $n=1$ the recurrence becomes

$$\begin{align*}
f(1+1)&=3f(1)^2-4f(1-1)^2\\
&=3\cdot2^2-4(-1)^2\\
&=12-4\\
&=8\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $f(2)=8$. Now you should be able to go ahead and calculate the other three requested values; just take them one at a time, because you need $f(3)$, for instance, in order to calculate $f(4)$.

Comment: f(5)=3(92,672)2 - 4(176)2 
    =2.576417485 x10

is my answer right? Im stuck at here...feel weird for the final answer.

Comment: @Raymond: You’re final answer should be all four numbers, $f(2)$, which you already have, $f(3)=3\cdot8^2-4\cdot2^2=176$, $f(4)=92672$, and $f(5)=25,764,174,848$, but you do appear to have calculated correctly, yes.

Comment: @Raymond: You’re very welcome.